# Check and delete stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have two table `tbl_item` and `tbl_category`,now all i want to do is to delete selected `category` from `tbl_catetgory` only if `tbl_item` has no record for selected category.if `category` is deleted stored procedure should return `1` else `0`.Please help.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_DelItemcategory]
@code int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql varchar(max)
    DECLARE @data VARCHAR(50)

set @sql='SELECT   Cat_code FROM    dbo.Tbl_ItemMaster WHERE   Cat_code = '+@code;

declare dB_cursor cursor for 
    SELECT   Cat_code FROM    dbo.Tbl_ItemMaster WHERE   Cat_code = @code

    open dB_cursor
    fetch next from dB_cursor into @data
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
            BEGIN         
                    set @sql='delete from Tbl_ItemCategory  where Cat_code='+@code;
            exec @sql
                    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @data  
            END  

        CLOSE db_cursor  
        DEALLOCATE db_cursor 

END
```

Comment: Any attempts so far??

Comment: Have you done anything yet? Propose your solution.

Comment: above sp will delete when record found but i want to delete only if no record found

Comment: have you try IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 ,then execute deletion

Comment: Have you ever heard of a JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the delete is based on given single Category, which is supplied as parameter @Code then why do you need cursor and some dynamic sql.

from your code it seems like Cat_Code column exist in both table; tbl_item and tbl_category.
also i am assuming "Retun 1" is only if one or more rows were deleted from tabe tbl_category.

```
    if not exists(select top 1 1 from tbl_item where Cat_Code = @code)
    begin
        DELETE tbl_category where Cat_Code = @code
        IF @@ROWCOUNT >0
        RETURN 1
    END
    Else
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_DelItemcategory]
@code int
AS
if not exists(select * from tbl_item where Cat_Code = @code)
begin
    if exists(select * from tbl_category where Cat_Code = @code)
    begin
        delete from tbl_category where Cat_Code = @code
        return 1
    end
end
return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add referential integrity ie a foreign key between your tables, to your database, this will happen automatically.

Additionally, there is no need to use either a cursor or dynamic SQL to achieve this